# Apache on Parallels CentOS fails to read OSX host files

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

The Parallels virtual server is CentOS 5.5, host system is OSX Snow Leopard

Within CentOS the host filesystem is mounted:

```
none          /media/psf   prl_fs   sync,nosuid,nodev,noatime,share     0       0
```

Apache is running within CentOS, and has the following alias pointing to the host filesystem

```
Alias /ca_media /home/django/soft-link-via-media-psf/media
<Location "/ca_media">
    SetHandler None
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
    FileETag MTime Size
</Location>
```

It gets bizzare at this point, from the host here is a demonstration. It seems that some files just won't get served - but others will. I can't see any distinction between the two (note that "pgevr" is my name for the CentOS machine as configured in `/etc/hosts`):

```
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ ls -l navagation_menu.js 
-rw-r--r--  1 millere  staff  702 Sep 21  2009 navagation_menu.js
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ curl http://pgevr/ca_media/er/js/navagation_menu.js
curl: (18) transfer closed with 702 bytes remaining to read
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ echo 'foo' > bar.js
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ curl http://pgevr/ca_media/er/js/bar.js
foo
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ ls -l bar.js 
-rw-r--r--  1 millere  staff  4 Oct 21 11:51 bar.js
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ file navagation_menu.js 
navagation_menu.js: ASCII text
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ file bar.js 
bar.js: ASCII text
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ cp navagation_menu.js bar.js 
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ curl http://pgevr/ca_media/er/js/bar.js
curl: (18) transfer closed with 702 bytes remaining to read
```

Is this a problem having to do with the two filesystems, or the type of mounted filesystem? How would you investigate this?

[ EDIT .. here is the result of the failed curl request with --trace-ascii ]

```
~/Projects/er_trunk/media/er/js$ curl --trace-ascii -  http://pgevr/ca_media/er/js/navagation_menu.js
== Info: About to connect() to pgevr port 80 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 10.211.55.9... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to pgevr (10.211.55.9) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 154 bytes (0x9a)
0000: GET /ca_media/er/js/navagation_menu.js HTTP/1.1
0031: User-Agent: curl/7.19.6 (i386-apple-darwin10.0.0) libcurl/7.19.6
0071:  zlib/1.2.3
007e: Host: pgevr
008b: Accept: */*
0098: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2010 16:51:19 GMT
<= Recv header, 31 bytes (0x1f)
0000: Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Oct 2010 21:55:19 GMT
<= Recv header, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: ETag: "2be-4932794f5ffc0"
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Accept-Ranges: bytes
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Content-Length: 702
<= Recv header, 31 bytes (0x1f)
0000: Cache-Control: max-age=604800
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Expires: Fri, 29 Oct 2010 16:51:19 GMT
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-Type: application/x-javascript
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 0 bytes (0x0)
== Info: transfer closed with 702 bytes remaining to read
== Info: Closing connection #0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 702 bytes remaining to read
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Apache logs after your curl attempt fails?

Comment: @Deutsch When I encounter the problem there are no errors, just logs of a bunch of either 200 or 206 requests. E.g. trying to view /images/ssl.gif fails and this is the only log line I can see: `domain:80 10.211.55.2 - - [25/Oct/2010:12:31:03 -0500] "GET /images/ssl.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2432 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.11 Safari/534.10"`

Comment: Yep, my Apache logs look like that as well. In the --trace-ascii output above you can see the 200 header come back as well...

Comment: It could be an issue between what features linux supports for that filesystem and what Apache is trying to do. Try adding "EnableSendfile Off" to your Apache config. More info is available at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

Comment: Deutsch sir, that was it! Please add an answer to claim the points that are rightfully yours.

Comment: I dunno, I gave it a shot on my install and it didn't work. I can try it again later... I'm running Parallels 6 if @EMiller isn't.

Comment: @dcousineau I've tried it on both Parallels 4.0 and 6.0 so far - this still does the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and uncommenting EnableSendfile Off in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf worked for me (as suggested by Deutch in a thread above).